# How do I install pandas for Python 3.4 in Windows?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

According to [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/install.html), this should work:

> **Installing from PyPI**
>
> pandas can be installed via pip from PyPI.
>
> pip install pandas
> This will likely require the installation of a number of dependencies, including NumPy, will require a compiler to compile required bits of code, and can take a few minutes to complete.

I've tried a couple of times now but it looks like it has a problem sorting out numpy?

```
Downloading/unpacking pandas
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Downloading/unpacking numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas)
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil>=2 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Installing collected packages: pandas, numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: \GnuWin32\bin";"C:\Program was unexpected at this time.

    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jonc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Jonc\\
setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jonc\AppData
Temp\pip-7c38q9vd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blas_info:

  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blas_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'

lapack_opt_info:

openblas_lapack_info:

  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build\src.win32-3.4

creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy

creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy\distutils

building library "npymath" sources

No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Running from numpy source directory.

C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: \GnuWin32\bin";"C:\Program was unexpected at this time.



----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jonc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Jonc\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(com
tattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7c38q9vd-
install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\numpy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jonc\pip\pip.log
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest using a self-contained package like winpython or anaconda where pandas and numpy comes pre-installed, they have user-friendly package managers and I generally use the unofficial win 64 builds here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for keeping up to date

Comment: On windows people usually use binary installer to install `numpy`. In the end I think `anaconda` is by far the best way to get scientific packages on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for 64-bit machines:

1. Download & install 64-bit Python: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-342/
2. Download the 64-bit version of numpy from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
3. pip install "numpy-1.9.2rc1+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"
4. pip install pandas

Comment: Thank you. Very happy to find this.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install pandas for Python 3.4 on Windows directly via pip, by simply choosing a slightly older version than the latest pandas version. At first, you update pip with

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Then you install version 0.21.0 instead of the latest version that is available for Python 3.4:

```
pip install pandas==0.21.0
```

The installation of pandas 0.21.0 should work out of the box for Python 3.4.0 - 3.4.4. You can list the available versions with:

```
pip install pandas==
```

If you try to install a later version, you need Visual Studio 2010 because the installer will try to build the sources.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working with the following:

1. Download the 32-bit version from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
2. pip install "numpy-1.9.2rc1+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl"
3. pip install six
4. pip install pandas

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already install python3.4 on your machine & you have windows OS
Simply type following On command prompt type:

> > pip install pandas

Make sure that you have "pip" installed on your system

for example:
c:\python34\Scripts>pip install pandas

Comment: Although this may solve the issue, I would recommend you to improve your answer by providing more information on why this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install pandas

Comment: The question specifies Python 3.4.